# how can I calculate how many each product a person has bought

Tags: python-3.x

how can I calculate how many each product a person has bought if I have a dictionary in which there is a surname, type of product and how much he bought it

Here is my code that makes a dictionary:

```
with open("Input_1.txt", "r") as file:
    dict_2 = {}
    for line in file:
        Surname = line.split() [0]
        Item = line.split()[1]
        Amount=line.split()[2]
        dict_2[Surname] = {Item: Amount}
    print(dict_2)
```

for example what it have to print:
{"Ivanov"{"aaa" 23} , "Petrov"{"aaa" 58} and so on

This is data from my txt file:

Ivanov aaa 1
Petrov aaa 2
Sidorov aaa 3
Ivanov aaa 6
Petrov aaa 7
Sidorov aaa 8
Ivanov bbb 3
Petrov bbb 7
Sidorov aaa 345
Ivanov ccc 45
Petrov ddd 34
Ziborov eee 234
Ivanov aaa 45
Ivanov paper 10
Petrov pens 5
Ivanov marker 3
Ivanov paper 7
Petrov envelope 20
Ivanov envelope 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a simple python solution you may change your code to:

```
with open('Input_1.txt', 'r') as file:
    dict_2 = {}
    for line in file:
        surname, item, amount = line.split()
        amount = int(amount)
        if surname not in dict_2:
            dict_2[surname] = {}
        if item not in dict_2[surname]:
            dict_2[surname][item] = amount
        else:
            dict_2[surname][item] += amount
```

This will give you the following dictionary:

```
Ivanov
     aaa : 52
     bbb : 3
     ccc : 45
     paper : 17
     marker : 3
     envelope : 5
Petrov
     aaa : 9
     bbb : 7
     ddd : 34
     pens : 5
     envelope : 20
Sidorov
     aaa : 356
Ziborov
     eee : 234
```

But it may be a good chance to give the `pandas` package a try. It's pretty useful when working with your kind of data. See the same code as above but using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
my_data = pd.read_csv('Input_1.txt', names=['Surname', 'Item', 'Amount'], sep=' ')
result = my_data.groupby(['Surname', 'Item']).sum()

print(result)
```

This gives you the following DataFrame:

```
                  Amount
Surname Item            
Ivanov  aaa           52
        bbb            3
        ccc           45
        envelope       5
        marker         3
        paper         17
Petrov  aaa            9
        bbb            7
        ddd           34
        envelope      20
        pens           5
Sidorov aaa          356
Ziborov eee          234
```